# How to prevent RequestLogsFeature from skipping a request after a Gateway call is made during request handling

Tags: servicestack

If a request handler uses the build-in `IServiceGateway` the request called by the gateway will be logged, not the original request.
e.g.

```
public object Post(DoSomething request)
{
    /* handle request */

    Gateway.Send(new DoSomethingElse());

    //Request.Items[Keywords.HasLogged] == true at this point

    return result;
}
```

The `RequestLogsFeature` will log the `DoSomethingElse` request, set `Request.Items[Keywords.HasLogged] = true` and not log the `DoSomething` request.

Is there a way to prevent `Gateway` from setting the `Keywords.HasLogged` flag to true? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [issue has already been resolved](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/5c360556439fb6491aea32fd8530421458a77d47#diff-6908776f34e6e1410bfd11c584dafa83) where ServiceStack won't log or flag In Process Requests. So if you upgrade to the latest v5.4 on NuGet you should no longer have this issue.